# Up-and downsides of a humanoid/common-sense question verification method as replacement of Captcha?

Tags: registration, captcha

I have thought about my own verification opposed to captcha / digit typing.
It would look like this, practically:

[image]

I am wondering if anyone that brainstorms can think of vulnerabilities of this sort verification as a replacement of common captcha, these questions can be tons and all in random combinations to eachother per 5 questions. The questions can only be answerred by a human from common sense. To protect from bots learning answers, I plan to add new questions on a daily to weekly basis incase I get to handle some pass-through or bot registrations, and make them blend in on the random combinations.

How safe is this approach and are there any vulnerabilities I have likely not thought of?

I just saw this on a forum and I suspect it's a self-made plugin, so I want to develop that too. If it's not and someone recognizes it (from SimplePortal board soft) please name/identify it.

**Another practical example**

[image: Another practical example]

Comment: Interesting! As long as you are not asking these for every access such as posting a comment. Otherwise, participation will drop off. For user creation, this could be effective. A couple of thoughts. No subjective questions. Your *Life is AWESOME!* question can be answered differently depending upon the day... ;-) ...and do not give answers on the screen or give misleading answers such as *up/down* for *true/false*. Otherwise, it is a 50/50% chance of guessing correctly.You can do this well if you think through it and try/make it for yourself. Think simple. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

- Your list of questions appears to limited.  An attacker just has to make a list of the questions that you use.   A good captcha would never ask the exact same question to two people.
- Your questions are going to turn away users.   This is a bunch of work to fill out.  A sizable percent of users are going to give up when they are faced with this much work.   Google is trying to make their captcha just a check box to make it easier on users.
- Most of your questions are easy for computers to answer.  Any math question is trivial to write computer software to answer.  "this or that" questions that give the answer in the question would be simple answer programatically.
- Some of your questions are difficult for humans to answer.   Even simple math problems make people think.   "Life is AWESOME!" doesn't have a "correct" answer.  People have to wonder if your system accepts both answers.